# Reverse convertion of tflite model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning

I have a trained tflite model from a public project. The original tensorflow / keras model is not available.

Is it possible to convert it back to keras / tensorflow model? 
Is it possible to use the tflite model as the trained part of the keras model?